# Multiple Google Charts on same page

Tags: javascript, charts

I have 2 charts but just one renders. I don't know where I made a mistake. What's wrong with my code? Can you help me?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.google.com/jsapi"></script>        
<script type="text/javascript">
     google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['bar']});
     google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

     function drawChart() {
          var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?php echo $satisfacao; ?>);
          var options = {chart: {title: 'Satisfação'}};
          var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
            chart.draw(data, options);  

          var data1 = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?php echo $clips; ?>);
          var options1 = {chart: {title: 'Clippings'}};
          var chart1 = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart_div1'));
            chart1.draw(data1, options1);       
     }
    </script>
    <div id='chart_div'></div>
    <div id='chart_div1'></div>
```